# Why does calling a function onclick not work all the time in Chrome and FF, but works in IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
      <SCRIPT>
function myFunction(atlasTrackingURL)
{
var atlasURL = atlasTrackingURL;
      if (!atlasURL) return;

            //Build a cache busting mechanism
            var timestamp = new Date();
            var queryString = "?random=" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 999999999999) +
                          timestamp.getUTCHours() + timestamp.getUTCMinutes() +                            

timestamp.getUTCSeconds();
            //Build the final URL
            atlasURL = atlasURL + queryString;

if (!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createElement
   || !document.appendChild)
                  {return false;}
            else
                  {     //Activate the JACTION call
                        var script = document.createElement("script");
                        script.type = "text/javascript";
                        script.src = atlasURL;
                        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
                    return true;
                  }
      }
      </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" onclick = "myFunction('http://view.atdmt.com/jaction/adoakb_PiggybackJSTest_1')">Test - Click Me</a>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It works in Internet Explorer every time, but rarely works in Chrome and Firefox. Why would this be?

Can these browsers not handle a function onClick very well? Are there any other options I can take?

I am trying to help a client figure out why one of their tracking tags are not firing off all the time on click in these browsers.

Thanks,

Comment: check dev tools and make sure some other element isn't overlapping

Comment: Reduce the problem space - does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/2Qegs/? If so, then something else is going on besides the browser.

Comment: That code does work, but I'm still confused why it would work in IE literally 100% of the time and not Firefox and Chrome. I thought it might be the way each browser interprets the code somehow, but I wouldn't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: What you have there is a race condition, you can't really depend on the script to load before the link sends you to another page.

Comment: Can I use a setTimeout function to help with this?

Comment: If so, can you show me how to use this?

Comment: @user2946613—the click listener should do something like cancel navigation, attach the new script element and perhaps use onload of the script element with a short delay to allow it to run, then do the navigation. However it's difficult to know why you want to wait until the link is clicked to add a script and what processing you are doing that requires it to run between the click and navigation. Perhaps you are using the wrong event? Have you considered [*beforeunload*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/history.html#unloading-documents)?

Answer (score 0):

You've got some kind of browser-dependent race condition going on, as Musa pointed out.

Try hiding the link initially, waiting for the document to load, and then adding the onclick attribute and revealing the link with javascript.

So, for example, change the link HTML to something like:

```
<a id="microsoft-link" href="http://www.microsoft.com" style="display: none;">Test - Click Me</a>
```

And add in your javascript, below the myFunction(), something like:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   var link_elem = document.getElementById("microsoft-link");
   link_elem.onclick = function() {
     myFunction('http://view.atdmt.com/jaction/adoakb_PiggybackJSTest_1'); 
   };
   link_elem.style.display = 'inherit';
 });
```

jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/m8VTy/3/

edit: I realized I may be misinterpreting what you're trying to do. What exactly is myFunction() supposed to accomplish ?

Comment: It's supposed to call the view.atdmt.com url which is a javascript file.

Comment: I need to make sure the javascript file executes before the href does

Comment: When I check in Chrome devTools, it says the view.atdmt.com javascript file fails before it executes using this method. Do you have any other suggestions?

The main problem is that I'm using both href and onclick, and the href redirects before the onclick can fully execute, so the javascript file is not getting called at all in Chrome and FF.